# How to use async functions in react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux

I'm using Redux with React.js here my handleSubmit method:

```
 handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await this.props.createCoupon({
        value: this.state.value,
        expiresDate: new Date(this.state.expiresDate)
    });
    this.props.fetchCoupons();
}
```

Logically fetchCoupons function will run after createCoupon finish and this works but im getting in my console `FETCH_COUPONS_REQUEST` before and after `CREATE_COUPON_SUCCESS`, how is that?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
handleSubmit = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
await this.props.createCoupon();
this.props.fetchCoupons();
 },

 createCoupon(){
     value: this.state.value,
     expiresDate: new Date(this.state.expiresDate)
    }
```